# Get the SObjectType of a record in Visualforce - is it possible?

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionfunction, dynamic-binding

I have a generic VF component that renders Action Links for records of arbitrary SObject types.
Iterating over SObjects in variable `record` I would like to use such a generic expression in my page:

```
{!URLFOR($Action[record.sobjectType].Edit, record.Id)}
```

This doesn't compile, but is there an alternative way to do this without having to resort to a Controller class.

Comment: I solved it in my specific use case by simply using /{!row.record.Id}/e instead. But what's the use of this whole dynamic Visualforce binding if there is no way to get the type of a record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_globals_objecttype.htm) suggests that there isn't a construct like the one you're looking for. In the examples of dynamic Apex/VF, the object type has to be calculated in Apex and then passed down to VF in a string:

```
// The sObject type as a string
public String getObjectType() {
      return(this.objType);
}
public String setObjectType(sObject newObj) {
    this.objType = newObj.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
    return(this.objType);
}



    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="4">
        <apex:commandButton value="View"
            action="{!URLFOR($Action[objectType].View, obj.Id)}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Edit"
            action="{!URLFOR($Action[objectType].Edit, obj.Id)}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Clone"
            action="{!URLFOR($Action[objectType].Clone, obj.Id)}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Delete"
            action="{!URLFOR($Action[objectType].Delete, obj.Id)}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is [a method](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_id.htm#apex_System_Id_getSObjectType) for this.

In your case it would look like this in your controller:

```
Schema.SObjectType sobjType = record.Id.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work.

Comment: The question is about a Visualforce expression not Apex code.

Comment: I'm aware of that - the chosen answer uses the same method that I posted.